# Filter for Multiple Criteria, Including List and Wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a filter on column A that will filter for both a list of data (`Range("Symbols")`), and for anything starting with the character `^`.

This is my code right now (only including the part that refers to the filter):

```
Dim ar As Variant

ar = Range("Symbols")
ar = Application.Transpose(ar)
ar = Split(Join(ar, ","), ",")

With sht1.Range("A1", sht1.Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ar, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=^*"
End With
```

For the above code I get the `Range("Symbols")` data only. The data starting with character `^` do not show.

I've also tried:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ar, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=^*"
```

For the above code I get all the data starting with character `^` but not the `Range("Symbols")` data.

And

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=^*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=ar, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

For the above code I get all the data starting with character `^` but not the `Range("Symbols")` data.

And

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(ar, "=^*"),Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

The above produces a Type Mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `AutoFilter` but you can with `Advanced Filter`.

In the code below, I copy `Range("Symbols")` to some other area on the worksheet and then delete it (find an unused area), but you could use `Range("Symbols")` itself if the range header is identical to the `Field1` header.

```
'Dim ar As Variant

'ar = Range("Symbols")
'ar = Application.Transpose(ar)
'ar = Split(Join(ar, ","), ",")

Dim rgCrit As Range
Range("symbols").Copy Range("AA2")

'copy criteria range to an unused area on the sheet
Range("AA1") = Range("A1")
Set rgCrit = Range("AA1").Resize(Range("symbols").Rows.Count + 1)

'add the ^* criteria to the range
rgCrit(rgCrit.Rows.Count, 1) = "^*"

With Sheet4.Range("A1", Sheet4.Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rgCrit
End With

'Doesn't clear filtered cells
'rgCrit.Clear
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rgCrit
        c.Clear
    Next c


End Sub
```

Here are some screenshots demonstrating the before and after

**Unfiltered Column**

[image]

**Allowed Symbols Range**

[image]

**Filtered Column**
*Note the strings that start with `^` are present*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately VBA doesn't read "^*" in a cell as that character and a wildcard. I think it's actually looking for a cell containing "^*".

Comment: @Gitty Now that I am at my computer, I will post some screen shots demonstrating the Filtering